# Is there a rich list of addresses of who owns how much of the Monero supply?

Tags: emission-curve

Is there a rich list of Monero addresses to see how distributed Monero is? Which address has the most Monero?

Comment: Hi. Unrelated to the question but please know that it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions, too! I notice you come with a batch of questions at the same time and I bet you already know the answer to some of them. Some effort in also answering the questions would be appreciated and would help share the load among other volunteers who are active on this site. I'll remove this comment after you've read it.

Comment: i'm still learning the system before i can make any answers. thanks!

Comment: Sure, and enjoy your ride! That's how I started as well =) I used to do research just to answer questions here, and learned a lot by doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one: http://moneroblocks.info/richlist

Spoiler: it's empty. Quoting the site:

> C'mon man. Really?
>
> I thought you knew...
>
> Monero is fundamentally
> private
>
> Really. It is.
>
> It is based in the Cryptonote protocol. It uses unique one-time
> addresses for each transaction so that only the receiver knows where
> the money went. This is good, believe me.
>
> And, as if that wasn't enough, it signs the inputs with ring
> signatures. And this is great because that signature only proves that
> someone in that group created it. That means only the sender knows
> where the money came from.